# Why does FigureCanvasTkAgg disables mouse scroll event in scrolled matplotlib GUI?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Hey I have made this GUI, that shows matplotlib plots in a tkinter interface with a scrolled canvas. But when the plots are added to the canvas the scroll event for the mouse doesn't work anymore. Im totaly new to tkinter so consider this when you check out the code if there can be improvements also. So here it is:

```
from Tkinter import *

import matplotlib
#matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

class App:

def __init__(self, master, figureList=[]):
    frame = Frame(master, bg='#00BFFF', borderwidth=1, relief=RAISED)
    frame.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

    master.title("Listed Plots")
    #Fullscreen for windows
    if os.name == 'nt':
        master.wm_state('zoomed')

    #Create a Canvas
    canvas=Canvas(frame,bg='#00BFFF', relief=SUNKEN)       
    canvas.config(highlightthickness=0) 

    #Create a Scrollbar Horisontal
    hbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=HORIZONTAL)
    hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
    hbar.config(command=canvas.xview)

    #Create a Scrollbar Vertical
    vbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=VERTICAL)
    vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
    vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

    canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
    canvas.pack(side=TOP,expand=True,fill=BOTH)

    #Create a Frame in the canvas
    canvFrame = Frame(canvas, bg='#00BFFF')
    canvFrame.pack()

    Label(canvFrame, text="Matplots of data", bg='#B4EEB4').pack(side=TOP,fill=X)

    plotNbr = 1
    windowHeight = 10

    for fig in figureList:
        Label(canvFrame, text="#Plotnumber: " + str(plotNbr), bg='#FF7F24').pack(side=TOP,fill=X)

        frm = Frame(canvFrame, bg='#9FB6CD')
        frm.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        self.canvasMPL2, self.canvasMPLToolBar2 = getCanvas(frm, fig)
        self.canvasMPL2.pack(side=TOP)
        self.canvasMPLToolBar2.pack(side=TOP)

        #Create space for the plot and tool bar.
        windowHeight = windowHeight + 680
        plotNbr = plotNbr + 1


    canvas.config(width=1200,height= windowHeight)
    canvas.config(scrollregion=(0,0,1200, windowHeight))

    canvas.create_window(0,0, anchor = NW, window = canvFrame, width = 1200, height = windowHeight)

    canvas.focus_set() #Doesnt work with FigureCanvasTkAgg, this steals the focus 
    #canvas.focus_force()
    #canvas.grab_set_global()

    #scrollwheel settings
    canvas.configure(yscrollincrement='25')

    def rollWheel(event):
        #print "Mousescroll"
        direction = 0
        if event.num == 5 or event.delta == -120:
            direction = 1
        if event.num == 4 or event.delta == 120:
            direction = -1
        event.widget.yview_scroll(direction, UNITS)

    canvas.bind('<MouseWheel>', lambda event: rollWheel(event))
    canvas.bind('<Button-4>', lambda event: rollWheel(event))
    canvas.bind('<Button-5>', lambda event: rollWheel(event))


plottedFigures = [] #To store matplotlib figures

def addPlottedFig(figure):
    '''
    Matplotlib figures to be shown in the GUI
    '''
    plottedFigures.append(figure)


def getCanvas(masterWidget, figure=None):
    '''
    Returns canvas of plot and canvas of tool bar
    '''
    if(figure==None):
        f = getHistoGramPlot() #For testing
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=masterWidget)
    else:
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=masterWidget)

    canvas.show()
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( canvas, masterWidget )
    toolbar.update()

    #return the plot and the toolbar
    return canvas.get_tk_widget(), canvas._tkcanvas

def initiate(FigureList=None):
    '''
    Start the GUI Application
    '''
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root, FigureList)
    root.mainloop()


def main():
    '''
    Shows 2 histograms plots in a tkinter GUI
    '''
    fig1 = getHistoGramPlot()
    fig2 = getHistoGramPlot()

    figList = [fig1, fig2]

    initiate(figList)

def getHistoGramPlot():
    '''
    Return a figure of a histogram
    '''
    mu, sigma = 100, 15
    x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6), dpi=100)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    n, bins, patches = ax.hist(x, 50, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.6)
    bincenters = 0.5*(bins[1:]+bins[:-1])
    mu = np.median(x)
    sigma = np.std(x)
    y = mlab.normpdf( bincenters, mu, sigma)
    l = ax.plot(bincenters, y, 'r--', linewidth=1)
    ax.set_xlabel('Values')
    ax.set_ylabel('Probability')
    xlimTop = max(x)
    xlimBottom = min(x)
    ax.set_xlim(xlimBottom, xlimTop)
    ax.grid(True)

    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a quick & dirty solution:

- Make the main canvas an attribute of your App class
- Make rollWheel a method of your App class
- Create your mousewheel binding on the window rather than the canvas. This will
  capture mousewheel events for all widgets inside the window.
- Scroll the canvas on mousewheel events

---

```
from Tkinter import *

import matplotlib
#matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

class App:

    def __init__(self, master, figureList=[]):
        frame = Frame(master, bg='#00BFFF', borderwidth=1, relief=RAISED)
        frame.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        master.title("Listed Plots")
        #Fullscreen for windows
        if os.name == 'nt':
            master.wm_state('zoomed')

        #Create a Canvas
        self.canvas = canvas = Canvas(frame,bg='#00BFFF', relief=SUNKEN)       
        canvas.config(highlightthickness=0) 

        #Create a Scrollbar Horisontal
        hbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=HORIZONTAL)
        hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
        hbar.config(command=canvas.xview)

        #Create a Scrollbar Vertical
        vbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=VERTICAL)
        vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
        vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

        canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
        canvas.pack(side=TOP,expand=True,fill=BOTH)

        #Create a Frame in the canvas
        canvFrame = Frame(canvas, bg='#00BFFF')
        canvFrame.pack()

        Label(canvFrame, text="Matplots of data", bg='#B4EEB4').pack(side=TOP,fill=X)

        plotNbr = 1
        windowHeight = 10

        for fig in figureList:
            Label(canvFrame, text="#Plotnumber: " + str(plotNbr), bg='#FF7F24').pack(side=TOP,fill=X)

            frm = Frame(canvFrame, bg='#9FB6CD')
            frm.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

            self.canvasMPL2, self.canvasMPLToolBar2 = getCanvas(frm, fig)
            self.canvasMPL2.pack(side=TOP)
            self.canvasMPLToolBar2.pack(side=TOP)

            #Create space for the plot and tool bar.
            windowHeight = windowHeight + 680
            plotNbr = plotNbr + 1


        canvas.config(width=1200,height= windowHeight)
        canvas.config(scrollregion=(0,0,1200, windowHeight))

        canvas.create_window(0,0, anchor = NW, window = canvFrame, width = 1200, height = windowHeight)

        canvas.focus_set() #Doesnt work with FigureCanvasTkAgg, this steals the focus 
        #canvas.focus_force()
        #canvas.grab_set_global()

        #scrollwheel settings
        canvas.configure(yscrollincrement='25')

##        def rollWheel(event):
##            #print "Mousescroll"
##            direction = 0
##            if event.num == 5 or event.delta == -120:
##                direction = 1
##            if event.num == 4 or event.delta == 120:
##                direction = -1
##            event.widget.yview_scroll(direction, UNITS)

        master.bind('<MouseWheel>', lambda event,s=self: self.rollWheel(event))
        canvas.bind('<Button-4>', lambda event: rollWheel(event))
        canvas.bind('<Button-5>', lambda event: rollWheel(event))

    def rollWheel(self, event):
        #print "Mousescroll"
        direction = 0
        if event.num == 5 or event.delta == -120:
            direction = 1
        if event.num == 4 or event.delta == 120:
            direction = -1
##        event.widget.yview_scroll(direction, UNITS)
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(direction, UNITS)    

plottedFigures = [] #To store matplotlib figures

def addPlottedFig(figure):
    '''
    Matplotlib figures to be shown in the GUI
    '''
    plottedFigures.append(figure)


def getCanvas(masterWidget, figure=None):
    '''
    Returns canvas of plot and canvas of tool bar
    '''
    if(figure==None):
        f = getHistoGramPlot() #For testing
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=masterWidget)
    else:
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=masterWidget)

    canvas.show()
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( canvas, masterWidget )
    toolbar.update()

    #return the plot and the toolbar
    return canvas.get_tk_widget(), canvas._tkcanvas

def initiate(FigureList=None):
    '''
    Start the GUI Application
    '''
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root, FigureList)
    root.mainloop()


def main():
    '''
    Shows 2 histograms plots in a tkinter GUI
    '''
    fig1 = getHistoGramPlot()
    fig2 = getHistoGramPlot()

    figList = [fig1, fig2]

    initiate(figList)

def getHistoGramPlot():
    '''
    Return a figure of a histogram
    '''
    mu, sigma = 100, 15
    x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6), dpi=100)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    n, bins, patches = ax.hist(x, 50, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.6)
    bincenters = 0.5*(bins[1:]+bins[:-1])
    mu = np.median(x)
    sigma = np.std(x)
    y = mlab.normpdf( bincenters, mu, sigma)
    l = ax.plot(bincenters, y, 'r--', linewidth=1)
    ax.set_xlabel('Values')
    ax.set_ylabel('Probability')
    xlimTop = max(x)
    xlimBottom = min(x)
    ax.set_xlim(xlimBottom, xlimTop)
    ax.grid(True)

    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you!For making the up and down keys also to work: `        master.bind('<Up>', lambda event,s=self: self.rollWheel(event))
master.bind('<Down>', lambda event,s=self: self.rollWheel(event))` with delta 38 and 40 in the rollWheel method.

Answer (score 1):

The indentation for `class App:` code was dedented improperly. I assume that `rollWheel` is a function defined within `__init__`.

Make this change:

```
    def rollWheel(event):
        #print "Mousescroll"
        direction = 0
        if event.num == 5 or event.delta == -120:
            direction = 1
        if event.num == 4 or event.delta == 120:
            direction = -1
        # Tell the canvas to scroll directly
        canvas.yview_scroll(direction, UNITS)  

    canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', lambda event: rollWheel(event))
    canvas.bind_all('<Button-4>', lambda event: rollWheel(event))
    canvas.bind_all('<Button-5>', lambda event: rollWheel(event))
```

For more information on `.bind_all` and tkinter binding in general check out [effbot's tutorial](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).